# Angular 2: Regex to accept only positve integers and no dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I got a input field with the type number. Now I'm trying to add a pattern to it that only allows positive integers and no dots or commas! But I cant find a good regex for it

so

**allowed**

- 0
- 01
- 100

**not allowed!**

- -1
- 1-
- 1+
- 1.0
- 1.1
- 1+
- +1
- 1,2

Comment: [\d] or [0-9] this is very simple and is not angular question. search and try before asking here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the pattern `/^[0-9]+$/` or even `/^\d+$/` to match your input

You need `^` and `$` in the pattern in order to match the whole word instead of part of it.

Comment: this is js question. your second regex is wrong. it has extra slash

Comment: I'm using string representation. However, thanks for your advise and I'll change it.

Comment: Both of them dont work. [0-9]+ still allows 1.0 and \\d+ doesnt allow numbers

Comment: Edited. You need `^` and `$` in the pattern